# Tensorflow resize with crop or pad a one-hot tensor

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0, padding, one-hot-encoding

The method `tf.image.resize_with_crop_or_pad` crops and/or pads an image to a target width and height. The padding, if any, is done using zeros. While such behaviour is generally good for images, it is not the best suited for padding one-hot segmentation masks, where for each pixel we have multiple channels with 0 everywhere but the channel associated with a specific semantic class:

```
z = 2
z_one_hot = [0, 0, 1]  # i.e. there is a 1 on the channel #2
```

In other terms, if we are pad a one-hot array with `tf.image.resize_with_crop_or_pad`, we would obtain pixels: `pad = [0, 0, 0]` instead of `pad_one_hot = [1, 0, 0]` (assuming the first index is the background class).

Is there any workaround to this behaviour?

Below, a simple snippet to better explain the problem:

```
x = get_one_hot_segmentation_mask()  # [batch_size, N, M, num_classes] 
x = tf.image.resize_with_crop_or_pad(x, target_height=N//2, target_width=2*M)
```

Comment: what's the expected behavior?

Comment: I would like the possibility to apply resize_with_crop_or_pad() on the different channels of x independently, using different values for each channel. For example, in my case I would like to pass an argument `pad_values = [1, 0, 0]` to say: pad with 1 on the channel #0, pad with 0 on the other channels